# extjs4 store set extraParam dynamically not working

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4.2

Good day. I have an unsettling error that I've encountered recently and I do not know where it came from or how it came about.

I have a form where I want to save data to the database upon button press which is handled by the controller. This is what I do in my controller:

```
var personStore = Ext.getStore('personBaseDetails');
var caStore = Ext.getStore('creditApplication');
var form = button.up('form').getForm();
var userId = personStore.first().get('ID');

//use this to update
if(caStore.count() < 1){
    var creditApplication = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    }, 'appName.model.creditApplicationModel');
    caStore.add(creditApplication);
}

var record = caStore.first();
form.updateRecord(record);

console.log("user id to be edited is = " + userId);
console.log("caStore count = " + caStore.getCount());

caStore.getProxy().extraParams = {
    selectedUserID: userId
};

// caStore.load();
caStore.sync({
    success: function(batch) {
        console.log(batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData['message']);
    },

    failure: function(batch) {
        console.log(batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData['message']);
    }

});
```

Here, I set the store extra param in order to use it in the php code query. However, the issue I have is that when I get the `selectedUserID` in the php code I have, I couldn't seem to get the extra parameter. If I commented out the `if(isset($_GET['selectedUserID'])){ .... }`, the query works (though the values are hardcoded as of now).

Here is what my store looks like:

```
Ext.define('app.store.creditApplication', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'app.model.creditApplicationModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: false,
            model: 'app.model.creditApplicationModel',
            storeId: 'creditApplication',
            clearOnPageLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    create: 'data/person/creditApplication/createCreditApplication.php',
                    read: 'data/person/creditApplication/readCreditApplication.php',
                    update: 'data/person/creditApplication/updateCreditApplication.php'
                },
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    encode: true,
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Now I'm dumbfounded since I have another code which is similar in the sense that I set the extraParam in the controller and the php code was able to receive and read it just fine. Note that both my stores do not have any `extraParam` property.

I've been stuck with this problem and I don't know how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try it like this... `caStore.load({ params: { selectedUserID: userId } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store does not have extraParam(s), proxy does. You can set it with:

store.getProxy().[setExtraParam(name, value)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-setExtraParam)